# Jekyll Tag List on a Page

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I'm attempting to display a list of tags using Jekyll. Here is what my HTML on the page looks like:

```
<ul>
  {% for tags in page.tags %}
    <li>{{ tags }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And this is the information in my front matter:

```
---
layout: template
title: Title
tags: all portfolio something
---
```

I am getting an output, but it is just creating a list like this:

- all portfolio something

instead of what I am trying to acheive, which is this:

- all
- portfolio
- something

Any troubleshooting on this would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: whtas your styling i.e. `css`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried on a new Jekyll website (with Jekyll 2.0.3), and the following front matter worked well (make sure to use `tags`, not `tag`:

```
---
layout: template
title: Title
tags: all portfolio something
---
```

You can also use a list:

```
---
layout: template
title: Title
tags:
- all
- portfolio
- something
---
```

Then, use in your post or in your layout:

```
<ul>
  {% for tags in page.tags %}
    <li>{{ tags }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If you still have a problem, consider upgrading Jekyll, providing a MWE or the output HTML/CSS.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it works perfectly. They will sing songs about you and your triumphs.

Answer (score 1):

For this **front matter**:

```
---
layout: template
title: Title
tags: all portfolio something
---
```

You can assign `page.tags | split:&nbsp;` into a variable to use for a `for` loop iteration:

```
{% assign tags = page.tags | split:&nbsp; %}
<ul>
    {% for tag in tags %}
    <li>{{ tag }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

It will output something like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>all</li>
  <li>portfolio</li>
  <li>something</li>
</ul>
```